# Bug in three.js loadOBJMTL loader?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

There appears to be a bug in the OBJMTL loader for three.js.  I have an obj/mtl/jpeg set of files that are giving some load errors.  They look like this:

"THREE.OBJMTLLoader: Unhandled line 4033/5601/6659" OBJMTLLoader.js:347

The offending line appears to have a continuation.  It ends with a backslash and the "4033/5601/6659" is on the next line (which is what the loader appears to be complaining about).  Any comment on this?

Comment: Try manually removing backslashes and concatenating the lines. three.js does not support non-triangular faces, so you may have a problem with your model.

Comment: K, I went through manually and joined up the lines and that got rid of the console errors.  Thanks for the tip on triangles only.  Any plans to deal with quads?  I'm using complex models that I find on the web for the app I'm playing around with.  My suspicion is they will many of them likely have quads in them.  Also, the rendering is kinda weird from different angles.  Like the wheels look weird.  Can I send you a screenshot so you can see what I mean?

Comment: Does "weird" mean inside out?

Comment: By weird, I mean like looking at them from the wrong angle.  Its like there's one jpg image and its done for a particular view and its used no matter what camera angle you look at it from in three.js.

Comment: Then the model creator needs to fix the textures. Can't be fixed software-wise.

Comment: If you are still having problems, then make a new post and show a screen shot, or better yet, a live example.

Comment: I load the same model with Blender and its renders perfectly.  I think there is some issue with three.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OBJMTLLoader` does not handle continuation lines. You will have to manually remove the backslashes and concatenate the lines.

By the way, the longer lines in the file can occur when faces have more then three vertices. three.js only supports triangular faces. (three.js used to support quads, but that feature has been removed.)

three.js r.67

Comment: Could you comment on why its does not handle continuation lines?  That seems like it would be easy to fix.  Can you comment on why support for quads was removed?  I'm not too familiar with the internals of three.js yet and I know a little about 3d graphics so I'd be interested in the motivation for removal.

Comment: 1. With 3 vertices per face, line continuations are not needed. 2. The primary reason was WebGL does not support quads anyway.